# How can i disable the text next to the cursor?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

How can i disable this text next to the cursor?

Does someone know how this is called?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THx51.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp

It is an alt attribute used for describing for instance, an image.

Comment: Do you know how to disable this?

Comment: I believe you are not able to disable this feature, perhaps if you find a suitable plugin for it, but standard settings don't allow manipulation of this as far as I know.

Comment: You can try this plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alt-text-engaged/eoldhncnldejmoalkfhcjodiamppliee I believe it should be able to disable alt text for everything.